# Python onedrivesdk - invalid_request error

Tags: python, python-3.x, onedrive

I want to upload files and create folders on OneDrive with Python. So i copied the code from the OnDrive GitHub [GitHub](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python), registered my App at Azure, copied the ID and created an secret. So far so good.

But now, if i run my code. The Browser opens asking for the permission to login automatically, agreed and then i get this error:

```
Exception: invalid_request
```

I think it has something to do with the `redirect_uri` because if i copy this into my browser i cant access it.

Here is my code:

```
import onedrivesdk
from onedrivesdk.helpers import GetAuthCodeServer

redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8080/'
client_secret = 'The secret i created on Azure'
scopes=['wl.signin', 'wl.offline_access', 'onedrive.readwrite']

client = onedrivesdk.get_default_client(
    client_id='The ID Azure created for me', scopes=scopes)

auth_url = client.auth_provider.get_auth_url(redirect_uri)

#this will block until we have the code
code = GetAuthCodeServer.get_auth_code(auth_url, redirect_uri)

client.auth_provider.authenticate(code, redirect_uri, client_secret)
```

I also tried it with an Proxy:

```
import onedrivesdk
from onedrivesdk.helpers import GetAuthCodeServer

from onedrivesdk.helpers import http_provider_with_proxy

redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8080'
client_secret = 'Secret created with Azure'
client_id = 'ID id got from Azure'
scopes=['wl.signin', 'wl.offline_access', 'onedrive.readwrite']

client = onedrivesdk.get_default_client(client_id, scopes=scopes)

auth_url = client.auth_provider.get_auth_url(redirect_uri)

code = GetAuthCodeServer.get_auth_code(auth_url, redirect_uri)

proxy = {
    'http': 'http://localhost:8888',
    'https': 'https://localhost:8888'
}
http = http_provider_with_proxy.HttpProviderWithProxy(proxy, verify_ssl=True)
auth = onedrivesdk.AuthProvider(http, client_id, ['onedrive.readwrite'])
client = onedrivesdk.OneDriveClient(redirect_uri, auth, http)

f = onedrivesdk.Folder()
i = onedrivesdk.Item()
i.name = 'New Folder'
i.folder = f

returned_item = client.item(drive='me', id='root').children.add(i)
```

That gives me this error message:

```
RuntimeError: Session must be authenticated 
            before applying authentication to a request.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works - e.g. it sends the info you want to send. However the credentials you have entered will of course return an invalid request - you're trying to connect to azure with:

```
client_id: 'The ID Azure created for me'
```

Which I'm pretty sure doesn't exists. The issue is you need an account & pass your script those (valid) account informations to connect to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 'The ID Azure created for me' is not what is written in my code. I registered my App on Azure and then Azure creates the client_id. I copied that into my code. I only changed it here on Stackoverflow because i dont now if anybody could abuse it.

Comment: Do you actually get "invalid request" or do you get "unauthorized client"? With your code, I actually get unauthorized client, not invalid request...

Comment: It is "invalid request" not in the browser but in my python console. The browser leaves a blank page after login.

Comment: I also receive the "code" but after that it failes with invalid request!

Comment: Right - but the Python console gave you "invalid request" likely because on the application-side, it received unauthorized client. Maybe the application's message doesn't bubble up into the python console, which then brings up a generic exception. But IMO you need to check your credentials, or perhaps on the application-side there is some parameters to make it public visible?

Comment: Could it be that i just cant access port 8080?

Comment: Or it could be that your app is not actually listening to that port. Are you positive onedrive is accepting requests on 8080?

Comment: It is used as an example on the GitHub page an anywhere else.This is some additional info on my error which is printed to my console:
custom_response = HttpResponse(response.status_code, response.headers, response.text)
After that comes: raise Exception(str(message["error"])) which is the invalid_request

Comment: Added example with an Proxy to my initial post. Gives me a new error message!